# Тогдашнее (время)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

Можно ли употреблять слово "тогдашнее" или оно просторечное?

Answer (score 1):

В словарях слово "**тогдашний**" помечено как разговорное, в то же время в письменных текстах оно часто встречается, например:

1. В «Слове о полку Игореве» отразился **тогдашний** человек, отразился писатель, высказалась историческая эпоха, начало Руси.
2. Самым популярным произведением **тогдашней** литературы была сентиментальная повесть.
3. В доме родителей Пушкина собирались просвещенные литераторы **тогдашней** Москвы.
4. Достоевский: «Беседка строена была бог весть когда, по преданию, лет пятьдесят назад каким-то **тогдашним** владельцем домика".

Answer (score 0):

Разговорное, не просторечное. Значит, в письменной речи нежелательно, а в бытовом разговоре - пожалуйста.

Comment: А учитель на уроке литературы может его использовать в значении "то" время?

Comment: Несолидно для учителя. Я такие слова никогда не использовала, а однажды услышала от учителя "встрела родителей", "нагинаться не надо". Вот и весь уровень преподавания сразу виден.

Comment: Но нужно быть терпимей, "тогдашнее время" всё-таки не "встрела".

Comment: В учебнике литературы Кутузова, который отличается особым вниманием к вопросам теории литературы, в одной из статей употребляется слово "взаправдашний" (то же самое образование прилагательного от наречия, с тем же суффиксом). Вот и думайте, можно ли учителю...

Comment: "Взаправдашний" - один раз и для выразительности... А это слово учительница употребляет постоянно... Дети говорят, что слух режет... Корректно сделать замечание учительнице или объяснить детям, что она имеет полное право использовать это слово?

Comment: Может, Вы всё-таки объясните детям, что слово не просторечное, а разговорное, но у Лопатина и такой пометы нет, значит, оно входит в нашу речь уже на правах нормы? Ведь это   так. Пусть сами посмотрят  в Интернете  словарь Лопатина и убедятся в этом, нормы же в его словаре закреплены. И учителю нужно потихоньку сказать, чтобы пореже употребляла разговорные слова при таких строгих ценителях, будет задумываться, прежде чем сказать.

Comment: @Людмила, у Лопатина, и *физрук* с *химичкой* без каких либо помет стоят. У этого словаря пометы и не предполагаются, насколько понимаю.

Comment: А, ну да, это же орфографический словарь, тогда не пойдёт, придётся ограничиться Ожеговым, пометой "разговорное".